# features issues not overriding

Tags: features

I have a feature that I copied from site A to site B. Site B is created using a profile install based on site A. Now I have to enabled a feature that I copied from A to B but whenever I enable this feature I always "overrides". I revert to the feature but it's always overriding. It's usually the field_base portion that has overrides. I have more than one feature that does this.  I dont want to recreate using DB settings. I want the feature settings. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. [image: You can see here the issue.]

Answer (score 0):

it was the actual features module itself. The latest version removed foreign keys which caused the overridden to be permanent.